# How to prepare the data to train Convolutional Gated Recurrent Unit (CGRU)?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, video-processing

For context, a CGRU is a variation of a recurrent neural network that uses a convolutional kernel instead matrix multiplication within its respective defining recurrent relations (update and reset gates, candidate hidden state) ([Ballas et.al 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06432.pdf)). It seems to be useful for video generation.

Originally I tried to build the network from scratch but then I found this [github repository](https://github.com/jhhuang96/ConvLSTM-PyTorch/tree/master) and decided to use that particular implementation for my own purposes. Now, since I'm quite new to both Deep Learning and programming in general, I'm having trouble training this thing on my data. My data is of shape (1000, 1000, 2, 8, 8) which can be understood as follows: 1000 images, each evolved in time 1000 times, each having 2 channels, and each of size 8x8. Now the repository's data processing script includes some methods for generating random 64x64 image sequences based on superpositions of MNIST digits which are of no use for me given that I already have each of my images evolved in time. In that sense, I tried to build a simpler dataset class, but I have not been able to use this to train the network using the same training loop given in the repo.

My attempt at building the dataset

```py
class TimeEvolvedSnapshots(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path, input_steps, output_steps, split_ratio=0.8, transform=None):
        super(TimeEvolvedSnapshots, self).__init__()
        self.dataset = complex_to_image(path).transpose((1, 0, 2, 3, 4))
        self.length = self.dataset.shape[0]
        self.input_steps = input_steps
        self.output_steps = output_steps
        self.transform = transform
        self.split_ratio = split_ratio

        self.train_length = int(self.length * self.split_ratio)
        self.test_length = self.length - self.train_length

        self.train_dataset = self.dataset[:self.train_length]
        self.test_dataset = self.dataset[-self.test_length:]

    def __len__(self):
        if self.transform:
            return int(self.train_length - self.input_steps - self.output_steps)
        else:
            return int(self.train_length - self.input_steps - self.output_steps)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        input_data = self.train_dataset[index: index + self.input_steps]
        output_data = self.train_dataset[index + self.input_steps: index + self.input_steps + self.output_steps]
        sample = {'input': input_data, 'output': output_data}

        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample

    def get_test_data(self):
        input_data = self.test_dataset[:-self.output_steps]
        output_data = self.test_dataset[self.input_steps:]
        sample = {'input': input_data, 'output': output_data}

        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample

    def __len__(self):
        if self.train:
            return int(self.length - self.input_steps - self.output_steps)
        else:
            return int(self.length * 0.2 - self.input_steps - self.output_steps)
```

I expected this to be enough to train the network, yet I haven't really figure out how to customize the training loop.